# Handles background activity

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm developing a music player app,My app work well on simulator,but on real device,it can't play when the app enter to the background or I tap the HOME button,I have config the `App plays audio or streams audio/video using AirPlay` info.plist and invoke `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` on `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application`I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Can you edit your question with your code that handles background activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the session of the `AVPlayer` like this

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&sessionError];
```

This will let you play your audio in background also.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,I have solved it by set the category `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback`,and I used to set the category `AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient` it can't continue to play when app enter to the background.